# CIDetector doesn't work in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection, cidetector

I am using CIDetector for facial detection (in conjunction with the YOLO framework for body detection).

When setting up the videoCapture I use `videoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = .portrait` so that the YOLO framework will work, but this immediately breaks the facial detection in that the coordinates it returns are just crazy.

I am aware that the faceDetector has a CIDetectorImageOrientation option, i.e.:

`let imageOptions: NSDictionary = [CIDetectorImageOrientation: NSNumber(value: exifOrientation), CIDetectorSmile: false, CIDetectorEyeBlink: false]
faces = faceDetector.features(in: ciImage, options: imageOptions as? [String : Any])`

I have tried all 8 enumerated values for `CIDetectorImageOrientation` in conjunction with `videoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = .portrait` and the face detector still spits out just the craziest coordinates.

For clarification, facial detection works just fine when `videoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation` is left to be it's default value (I think it's landscape left?).

It seems `CIDetector` and `videoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = .portrait` can't live in harmony.

My question is, is there something I'm missing that will make CIDetector work with `videoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = .portrait`?

Comment: That's not how you post code here.

Comment: If detection doesn't work, that's because you are not selecting the right image option.